# Is it possible for an attacker to change an email-attachment of a received email client-side and synchronize it via IMAP with Webmailer?

Tags: email, attacks, imap

an attacker manipulated the IBAN of an invoice.pdf attached to a received email. The question remains, can said attacker manipulate/change such a pdf client-side and cause an IMAP synchronization with the webmailer provided by a hoster?

I couldn't find a solution to this attack scenario, maybe you guys can provide a hint.

best

Answer (score 1):

If somebody has IMAP access to your email account they can replace an existing mail with a new version - see [IMAP - editing a draft or existing message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945041/imap-editing-a-draft-or-existing-message). This gets reflected to the mail server and thus to all connected clients too.

This does not mean that this has actually happened in your situation but is a possible attack path.

Answer (score 0):

IMAP allows to edit messages stored server-side and a proper IMAP client verifies whether the downloaded message matches what's stored on the server which means this attack is very much possible.

PGP/digital signature allows to prevent this.